# "form action" and "form submit onclick" to be both executed

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, jdbc

I am writing a basic HTML Form which interfaces with JDBC to pass on the values to the DB.

Here are two lines of my code :

```
<form id="splash" action="http://localhost:8080/Practice01/DatabaseAccess" method="post">

<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

The current output is, when i submit the form, the pade is directed to http://localhost:8080/Practice01/DatabaseAccess. But i want to open another page on submit (or execute myFunction). A thank you page. How do i achieve this.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: They should both be executed the way you've written it.

Comment: But that is not the case in case of my page. If i add the "onclick", only that function is being executed. Else, the "action" trigger is being called.

Comment: Does `myFunction()` use `event.preventDefault()`? That will prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: @Barmar : No. I havent used any preventDefault in my JS.

Answer (score 0):

create a code behind file to perform database operation and the redirect the code behind page to the page you want to open.

for example:

```
<form id="splash" action="<codebehindpage>" method="post">

<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

in the

```
response.redirect(<page you want to open>)
```